# How to install the `htop` manpage?

Tags: 20.04, manpage, htop

I have `htop` installed via snap, but apparently the man page (`man htop`) is not installed. Is it possible to install this?

Comment: Do you have the man info that needs to be added?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/htop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man-page for Snap'ed `htop` is already installed into `/snap/htop/current/usr/local/share/man/man1/htop.1` . You can access it using

```
man htop -M /snap/htop/current/usr/local/share/man/man1/htop.1
```

which is strange.

I have reported this as a bug at https://github.com/maxiberta/htop-snap/issues/11 .

---

Notes and thoughts:

1. The most official online manpage is here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man1/htop.1.html
2. Using Snap for system management app is irrational. Better way is to remove it and use deb-based version - `snap remove htop` followed by `sudo apt-get install htop` .

Comment: Thanks for your answer! According to the reactions to the bug reports, `snapd` does not support man pages (yet?). I'm not even sure why I installed the snap version of `htop`, ap it is more up to date though (3.0.4 vs 2.20 in `apt`).